# Can I migrate my jQuery projects to ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS, I know that react is about declaring the way something should render, giving it some data and poof, when the data changes, it renders those changes.
But if I want to manipulate the DOM, an example change a color, create a accordion, make animations, add and remove a class, etc.
React can do that? Could I migrate my jQuery projects to Reactjs without any problem?

Comment: It will take some skill and experience, but yes, for the most part

Comment: Short answer is Yes. Long answer is its complicated. React can co-exist with other libraries. But, directly manipulating a DOM is not a good practice in React. So, on click of a button, you will handle the event and modify a state. Then react re-renders and based on the state you will append a className.

Comment: What worked for me is that, forget everything you know about jQuery and start with 0 knowledge and look at how react is expecting you to work. Once you get a fair understanding, then you can start comparing and contrasting with jquery patterns / practices.

Comment: Yes, you can but for simple solutions, you might want to stick to jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is kind of dying off now for a reason - a lot can be accomplished with pure JavaScript. If you're interested in interactive components and things of that nature, check out Material UI. MUI has TONS of customization options.

Comment: This is not really a suitable question for this site as there is no absolute answer but only opinions. But since you asked, my answer would be yes. one of the many beauty of Javascript is its *chaotic* nature, not one framework/library can completely dominate the web, you can still write a fully functional app using native js too. So can one thing replace another thing and do everything the others can do? Of course, but it all comes down to personal preference and performance only. You like virtual dom? React. You like manipulate the dom directly? jQuery.

Comment: Ummm i got it, so it's a bad practice to mix both libraries in a same project?

Comment: Same Page - Is ok, but within a react component is not advisable and may lead to subtle issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches for that task, a complete list is [here in the official Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html). Either use React as a Wrapper on top of your jQuery Application or Translate your jQuery App to a React App.
From the official Docs

> React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover.
>
> This does not mean it is impossible or even necessarily difficult to combine React with other ways of affecting the DOM, you just have to be mindful of what each is doing.
>
> The easiest way to avoid conflicts is to prevent the React component from updating. You can do this by rendering elements that React has no reason to update, like an empty .

Here is a medium article that may help you.

[How-my-team-converted-our-website-from-jquery-to-react-in-small-steps](https://medium.com/@andreasmcd/how-my-team-converted-our-website-from-jquery-to-react-in-small-steps-cd4390f0a146)